# Comparing and editing an array

Tags: javascript

There are two arrays:

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 123,
    stock: [
      {
        colors: [{ color: "red", stock: 12 }],
        size: "S",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 321,
    stock: [
      {
        colors: [{ color: "blue", stock: 10 }],
        size: "L",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

and

```
const incart = [
  {
    id: 123,
    color: "red",
    qty: 1,
    size: "S",
  },
  {
    id: 321,
    color: "blue",
    size: "L",
    qty: 2,
  },
];
```

When a user purchases the items they have in their cart. I'd like to update the products array stock object if the color and size match.
I'm thinking about a filter and reduce but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: People downvoting a new user with no explanation or questions at all. StackOverflow won't be around much longer. Can you please update your question to give an example of what you are trying to accomplish.  Such as, "For example , Given the following items in the cart, I would like to change the red quantity from 12 to 11 and the blue quantity from 10 to 8.

Comment: Ok, i understand, I'll elaborate more next time

Comment: Please edit your question now, an elaborate further.

Comment: @TurtlesS : It would be good if you just describe the problem, not business workflow.  One more thing add some jsfiddle try.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const products = [
  {
    id: 123,
    stock: [
      {
        colors: [{ color: "red", stock: 12 }],
        size: "S",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 321,
    stock: [
      {
        colors: [{ color: "blue", stock: 10 }],
        size: "L",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const incart = [
  {
    id: 123,
    color: "red",
    qty: 1,
    size: "S",
  },
  {
    id: 321,
    color: "blue",
    size: "L",
    qty: 2,
  },
];

incart.forEach((curr) => {
  const { id, color, qty, size } = curr;
  const isExist = products.find((obj) => obj.id === id);
  if (isExist) {
    const stockObj = isExist.stock.find((s) => s.size === size);
    if (stockObj) {
      const colorObj = stockObj.colors.find((c) => c.color === color);
      if (colorObj) colorObj.stock -= qty;
    }
  }
});

console.log(products);
```

Comment: Why downvote, Answered exactly what OP wants

Comment: I didn't downvote but some users downvote answers to bad questions to avoid Stack Overflow becoming a free code writing service: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions